# The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, heroku

I am deploying my ASP .Net Core Web API using Heroku and this error occurs when calling Image.FromStream(memoryStream) function:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libgdiplus' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibgdiplus: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Even though using `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils libgdiplus libc6-dev` in Docker file, this error still occurs in Heroku only (it doesn't occur in localhost).

Can anyone help me for the solution?
I'm doing my capstone project so very appreciate getting your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to fix that .Net 6 in Linux (which OS heroku is using to deploy) doesn't support System.Drawing library anymore. So I decided to change the System.Drawing library by ImageSharp library.
You can find the information here for changes:
[Microsoft Learn - System.Drawing.Common only supported on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above all you have to do - is to add to dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        libc6-dev \
        libgdiplus \
        libx11-dev \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

and to add to project root file named : runtimeconfig.template.json

```
{
  "configProperties": {
    "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
  }
}
```

From [Microsoft Learn | System.Drawing.Common config switch removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/7.0/system-drawing) it states:

### Old Behavior

> Prior to .NET 6 and earlier, using the System.Drawing.Common package did not
> produce any compile-time warnings, and no run-time exceptions were
> thrown. In .NET 6 and earlier, you could set the System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport
> runtime configuration setting to re-enable non-Windows support.

### New Behavior

> Starting in .NET 7, the System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport switch has
> been removed and you can no longer use the System.Drawing.Common
> package on non-Windows operating systems.